# Adding a new consortium definition to existing running network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

EYFN allows to add an organization Org3 to existing channel "mychannel". I am trying to add add Org1 and Org3 to a new channel, by dynamically creating the channel in a running network. For this, I understand, there is a need to define consortium with Org1 and Org3.

when following the document, it was mentioned "In practice, consortium definition X2 has been added to the network configuration NC4. We discuss the exact mechanics of this operation elsewhere in the documentation." (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/network/network.html)

Is it possible to do this by updating the network configuration? or any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,it is possible,Instead of fetching the application channel,you must fetch the system channel block and add the new organization into the existing consortium,and add a new profile in the configtx and genarate a new transaction file and create your new channel

Comment: When I tried pulling system channel using peer channel command, its giving error {FORBIDDEN}

Comment: `# peer channel fetch config ord_config_block.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c byfn-sys-channel --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
2019-06-14 15:56:21.222 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2019-06-14 15:56:21.245 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Got status: &{FORBIDDEN}
Error: can't read the block: &{FORBIDDEN}

Comment: Hi kruparkar, please refer the following link https://github.com/rohitadivi/Reconfigure-BYFN/blob/master/Create_channel.md

Comment: The cause of the {FORBIDDEN} error is due to not setting the orderer environment in cli. The link is very helpful and now able to create a new channel in the running byfn network. Many thanks to @sudharsanan.k.

Comment: `root@4dde55597899:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer channel list
2019-06-17 17:41:19.406 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Channels peers has joined: 
jkchannel
mychannel
`

Comment: Do you know how to fetch the system channel using node sdk?